# facing difficulty in writing query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to write query in which the column name enter_mode of the table Attendance  value is not equal to check_in that means he is not checked in for that day OR if the count of the records when  same column name value is equal to check_out  is greater than 1 that means he is already checked out.
using sqlite

```
below is my query

SELECT * FROM Attendance 
WHERE emp_id="+emp_id+" 
   and cdate='"+cdate+"' 
   and enter_mode!='check_in' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Attendance 
WHERE emp_id="+emp_id+" 
   and cdate='"+cdate+"' 
   and enter_mode!='check_out'
```

Please help me to solve this issue.Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post the error or incorrect results.

Comment: @Segfault I am writing query in sqlite db, so after executing the required sql statement success method is called in which I have to show alert when he is not checked in for that day or he is already checked out for that day how to write?

Comment: Try using the sqlite3 command line tool to troubleshoot the query

Comment: See this query will work only when he is not checked in for that day but not able to meet second requirement.

Comment: Do you have any record at all for this employee in Attendance table when employee has not checked in for that day? If no, then you can't just get any result for this day, at least not without help of other tables.

Comment: Show some example data, and the desired result(s).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the second part:

```
SELECT * FROM Attendance 
WHERE emp_id="+emp_id+" 
   and cdate='"+cdate+"' 
   and enter_mode='check_out'
GROUP BY emp_id
HAVING COUNT(emp_id) > 1
```

By the way, you should always paste your table definition.

Comment: I have to meet both conditions in a single query :( below is my table structure                                                         CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Attendance (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,emp_id INTEGER, name TEXT  , cdate TEXT,ctime TEXT,enter_mode TEXT,pin_no TEXT,  reason TEXT,image BLOB, flag INTEGER DEFAULT 0)

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem, what emp_id means, etc. Anyway, try this part separately, If it gives you the results you expect then try doing a union as in your pasted sql. My advice: try to solve one problem at the time.

Comment: Hi, below query has error using phonegap                     db.transaction(function(tx) {
                         var query = "SELECT * FROM Attendance WHERE emp_id="+emp_id+" and cdate='"+cdate+"' and enter_mode!='check_in' UNION SELECT * FROM Attendance  WHERE emp_id="+emp_id+" and cdate='"+cdate+"' and enter_mode='check_out' HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 GROUP BY emp_id ";
                         alert(query);
                        tx.executeSql(query, [],
                               queryCheckoutValidate, errorCB);
                    });

Comment: I'm almost sure this works in mysql, but haven't tried it in sql lite. Try changing the having clause to `HAVING COUNT(emp_id) > 1`. Again, I'd recommend you to try just that part of the query and try it isolated (just the sql code in a console or something like that, not in your code). Hope it helps.

Comment: PS: `GROUP BY` needs to go before `HAVING`.

Comment: Hi, I have isolated them becuase of the complexity.Thanks :)